Short circuit fault in step down transformer
A step down transformer connect a high voltage network and secondary is open. The question is what happened when short circuit in two  terminals of hv side?
Does the short circuit current through the transformer or not?

No current will flow through primary, no current will flow through secondary.
Also there will be zero voltage across priamary and secondary also.
All current flows through short.
